# Custom Color Picker TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg, color-picker

I am using TinyMCE to for an WYSIWYG editor on my site, and I want to add a custom color picker to the editor in addition to the existing colorpicker using forecolor. I found this http://fiddle.tinymce.com/lwcaab/16 and used it to get the button to show up, but there are 2 problems. I need to filter the colors that show up in that button (only show a couple of colors), and when you click the color, it doesn't change the font color in the editor.

```
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.ExamplePlugin', {
    createControl: function(n, cm) 
        {
            switch(n)
            {
            case "universityColors":
               var o = {};
               ed=tinyMCE.activeEditor;
               o.scriptURL = ed.baseURI.getURI();
               o['class'] = 'mce_forecolor';
               o.title='University Font Colors';
               o.scope=this;
               o.image = '../images/uor.ico',
               o.onclick = function (color) { console.log('clicked',color);/*this.cs.showMenu(); if (this.o.onClick) this.o.onClick(c);*/};
               o.onselect = function (color) {console.log('selected',color); /*this.color=this.o.color=c; if (this.o.onSelect) this.o.onSelect(c);*/};

                var mcsb = cm.createColorSplitButton('universityColors', o);

                // return the new ColorSplitButton instance
                return mcsb;
            }
            return null;
        }
   });
tinymce.PluginManager.add('universityColorPicker', tinymce.plugins.ExamplePlugin);
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector: "tinyMCE",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "emotions,spellchecker,advhr,insertdatetime,preview, -universityColorPicker", 

     // Theme options - button# indicated the row# only
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,|,code,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor, universityColors",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "insertdate,inserttime,|,spellchecker,advhr,,removeformat,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions",      
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,


    });
```

I have made a fiddle to work of of also at: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/jYcaab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made that older fiddle :)
Here your modified fiddle that limits the colors: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/jYcaab/1

Applying the font to the content is another story.
Update: The font gets applied now: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/jYcaab/2

Comment: Awesome Thariama. Works perfectly. Is there any way to make the standard color picker have the default colors and the new color picker to only have the specific colors we are looking for?

Comment: sure, all you need to do is to define your own color_set define it in your init and use it later on with editor.getParam('my_own_color_set')

Comment: Here is a link to my question about how to create the color_set. If you get a chance, any help would be appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768671/create-custom-color-set-tinymce

Comment: Nevermind, after reading through the code you gave me, I was able to figure out what needed to be done. Please post your answer to my other question though so I can give you another +1